# Как вывести дату типа date в виде "dd-MM-yyyy"?

Tags: jsp, дата, mysql

Как дату типа date можно вывести в виде "dd-MM-yyyy"? По умолчанию она выводится так: "yyyy-MM-dd 00:00:00.0".
Пытаюсь так:

```
<td><calendar:parseDate value="${user.birthdate}"
pattern="dd-MM-yyyy"/></td>
```

Тогда выходит такая ошибка:

> javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: In &lt;parseDate&gt;, value attribute can not be parsed: "2014-08-18 00:00:00.0"

UserDaoImpl:

```
                 ...
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        public List<User> listUser() {

            return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from User")
                    .list();
                 ...
               }
```

UserServiceImpl:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Transactional
    public List<User> listUser() {
        return userDao.listUser();
    }
```

Метод в классе UserController.java, который получает данные и вызывается в menu.jsp:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/user/list", method = RequestMethod.GET)
       public String getUsers(Map<String, Object> map) {
        map.put("user", new User());
        map.put("userList", userService.listUser());
        map.put("categoryList", categoryService.listCategory());
          return "list-user";
                    }
```

menu.jsp:

```
<table class="menu">
    <tr>
     ...
<td><span class="space"><a href="/user/list" title="Users">
<spring:message code="label.user"/></a>
</span></td>
    ...
</tr>
</table>
```

User.java:

```
package com.springapp.mvc.domain;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.Collection;

@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User implements Serializable{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String surname;
    @Column(columnDefinition = "enum('male','female')")
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Gender gender = Gender.male;
    private Date birthdate;
    private String address;
    private String tel;
    private String email;
    private String login;
    private String password;
    private String confirmPassword;
    private boolean enabled;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "category_id")
    private Category category;
    private String comment;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinTable(name="user_role",
            joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="user_id")},
            inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="role_id")})
    private Collection<Role> roles;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getSurname() {
        return surname;
    }

    public void setSurname(String surname) {
        this.surname = surname;
    }

    public Gender getGender() {
        return gender;
    }

    public void setGender(Gender gender) {
        this.gender = gender;
    }

    public Date getBirthdate() {
        return birthdate;
    }

    public void setBirthdate(Date birthdate) {
        this.birthdate = birthdate;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public String getTel() {
        return tel;
    }

    public void setTel(String tel) {
        this.tel = tel;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getLogin() {
        return login;
    }

    public void setLogin(String login) {
        this.login = login;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getConfirmPassword() {
        return confirmPassword;
    }

    public void setConfirmPassword(String confirmPassword) {
        this.confirmPassword = confirmPassword;
    }

    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return enabled;
    }

    public void setEnabled(boolean enabled) {
        this.enabled = enabled;
    }

    public Category getCategory() {
        return category;
    }

    public void setCategory(Category category) {
        this.category = category;
    }

    public String getComment() {
        return comment;
    }

    public void setComment(String comment) {
        this.comment = comment;
    }

    public Collection<Role> getRoles() {
        return roles;
    }

    public void setRoles(Collection<Role> roles) {
        this.roles = roles;
    }

}
```

Comment: Очень странно, ну для полной картины.. еще класс User покажите. 

Потом попробуйте сделать простой пример передайте map.put("date", new Date()); и соответственно отобразите так как я писал в jsp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте вот так

```
   <%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>
    ...
    <fmt:formatDate value="${user.birthdate}" pattern="dd-MM-yyyy" />
```

либо через **SimpleDateFormat**

Comment: Если так:

    <%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>
        ...
        <fmt:formatDate value="${user.birthdate}" pattern="dd-MM-yyyy" />

 тогда выходит та же ошибка, что и раньше. А так:

    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");

тогда выводится в таком виде: "1999-02-18 00:00:00.0". И при этом новую дату получается добавить только через mysql.

Comment: В виде "1999-02-18 00:00:00.0" выводится только в браузере, в mysql выводится так: "1999-02-18". Что означает ноль в конце после точки?

Comment: user.birthdate - какой тип? java.util.Date?

Comment: да, user.birthdate типа java.util.Date.

Comment: Что-то очень странно, проверил только что у себя, все прекрасно работает.

Ну покажите тогда свой контроллер, или место где вы передаете переменные(интересует ${user.birthdate} ) в jsp

Comment: вот user.jsp:

...
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>
<body>
<c:if test="${!empty userList}">
<table class="user-table">               
<tr><th><spring:message code="label.birthdate"/></th>
     ...     </tr>
<c:forEach items="${userList}" var="user">
<tr> ...
<td><fmt:parseDate value="${user.birthdate}" pattern="yyyy-MM-dd"/></td></tr>
</c:forEach>
</table>
</c:if>
</body>

Comment: в контроллере все, что связанно с датой это вот этот код:

     @InitBinder
        public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder)
        {
            SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");//, new Locale("en", "EN")
            dateFormat.setLenient(false);
            binder.registerCustomEditor(Date.class, new CustomDateEditor(
                    dateFormat, true));
        }

Comment: С этим все понятно, меня интересует объект user и то как вы его передаете? место где вы достаете данные из базы и передаете во view

Answer (score 0):

Получилось только вот так:

```
    <%@ taglib prefix="calendar" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>
    ...
    <td><calendar:formatDate  value="${user.birthdate}"
                        pattern="dd-MM-yyyy"/></td>
```